# Jquery Mobile - nested list items using same href

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a list I am creating dynamically. The content looks good BUT each link points to the same page link:

I start with an empty list:

```html
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="profile2" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    </ul>        
</div>
```

I use `$('#profile2').append` to build the list and use `$('#profile2').listview("refresh");` to refresh the list after each new link is inserted.

Here is a sample of code after the list has been generated:

```html
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="profile2" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <li><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
            <div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#/demo?a=53&amp;b=-7&amp;ui-page=profile2-0" class="ui-link-inherit">
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Headin1</h3>
                <p class="ui-li-desc">Content 1</p></a><
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
            <div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#/demo?a=53&amp;b=-7&amp;ui-page=profile2-0" class="ui-link-inherit">
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Headin2</h3>
                <p class="ui-li-desc">Content 2</p></a><
            </div>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div>
        </li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

**NOTE the href for both links refers to profile2-0**

Interestingly, the pages generated for the child links have the same tabindex (0), as well as the same data-url. This is the code for both pages:

```html
<div data-role="page" data-url="/demo?a=53&amp;b=-7&amp;ui-page=profile2-0" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-a">
   CONTENT.....
</div>
```

I use `listview("refresh")` to refresh the styling, should this also take care of ensuring the page items are uniquely labeled?

Of course, this should be taken care of by JQM, but I cannot see a way to programmatically set a sub page link when creating the list item to ensure the links are unique.

Comment: probably an error in your code building the list?

Comment: Are you saying there is an error? (Or is this just a suggestion?) Can you point out where the error is to help move this forward?

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the `a` tag?

Comment: you did not provide the code which builds the list... therefore this is only an assumption that the error might be there... you might want to provide that code, too? and concerning your question  `should this also take care of ensuring the page items are uniquely labeled?` no, this needs to be done by your code... and `listview("refresh")` is only necessary once at the end after building the list

Comment: why would you assume `JQM` should fix or change your `href` links?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I use append() to programmatically add items to my nested listview, and after each item is added I call listview('refresh'). I end up with a correct looking list, but all items's href's point to #listPage&ui-page=myList-0 and bring up the page that belongs to the item at the bottom of the list. What's going on here?

Comment: Show your `$('#profile2').append` code

Comment: It may not be relevant, but as of $.mobile 1.3.0, nested lists have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been pointed out by Taifun, you probably have a problem in the code generating the list items (that you did not provide).

I tried this code, and did not face any issue:

```
<script>
        $(document).on("pageshow", function(){
            for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
                $("#profile2").append('<li><a href="/test/' + i + '">test ' + i + '</a></li>');
            }
            $("#profile2").listview('refresh');
        });
    </script>
```

Hope that helps.